# Is there any other sparse matrix data in matlab built-in file?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, sparse-file

I want to do some numerical examples solving large sparse linear system `Ax=b`. And I want to use some  data from Maltab itself because this experiments are easily reproduced any time using Matlab. For example,

```matlab
load west0479.mat
A = west0479;
b = sum(A,2);
```

Using these codes, I can obtain a sparse matrix linear system.
I want to ask whether there are some other sparse matrix data in Matlab? If so, please give me some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

It is straightforward to check this. `west0479` resides in the `demos` folder where all such samples are kept.

```
>> which west0479.mat
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\matlab\demos\west0479.mat
```

We can get a list of the `.mat` files in this folder which might contain sparse matrices.

```
>> files = dir(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','demos','*.mat'))

files = 

  41×1 struct array with fields:

    name
    folder
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

Each of these files can be loaded and checked for sparse variables. Let's make an array from these checks and use it to index the list of files, so only files containing sparse matrices are returned:

```
>> files(arrayfun(@(f) any(structfun(@issparse,load(fullfile(f.folder,f.name)))),files))

ans = 

  struct with fields:

       name: 'west0479.mat'
     folder: 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\matlab\demos'
       date: '14-Mar-2004 15:32:24'
      bytes: 12580
      isdir: 0
    datenum: 7.3202e+05
```

`west0479` is the only one.

Comment: thanks very much Prof. Will. So, if I want to use some sparse matrix to do numerical experiments, where can I get the data of sparse matrix?